# What is the origin of the name of Form 10-K?

Tags: united-states, investing, terminology, financial-statements, sec

I am assuming that Form 10-Q stands for quarterly, though I can't derive a good reason for the 10.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_10-K):

> The name of the Form 10-K comes from the Code of Federal Regulations (CFR) designation of the form pursuant to sections 13 and 15(d) of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934 as amended.

But I couldn't find it on [this law site](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/13/chapter-I). And I am not well-informed about the structuring of laws and have no idea if these numbers are even representing "sections".

So does anyone have an idea where the terms come from?

Sidenote (unrelated): Probably I could ask this in the [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com) as well, but I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: I doubt English.SE would allow this question.

Comment: I asked a friend who is a corporate securities lawyer and has been practicing for more than 25 years, and even she doesn't know!

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia sentence is a little bit ambiguous, and a little bit wrong. In particular, I can't find a section 15(d) in the [Securities Exchange Act of 1934](https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/1120). (Perhaps a later amendment changed the numbering, such that there is now a section 15(d).) But section 13(a)(2) does indeed indicate that the "Commission" has the authority to require annual and quarterly reports. (This is presumably the Securities and Exchange Commission, but I can't find the term "Commission" defined in the 1934 Act anywhere. Interestingly, "Commission" explicitly refers to the Federal Trade Commission in the [Securities Act of 1933](http://www.legisworks.org/congress/73/publaw-22.pdf).)

The 1934 Act didn't specify the name of the form -- only that the Commission may prescribe such forms.

The way the Commission then prescribes such reports is via the Code of Federal Regulations. In this case, it is in [Section 249.310 of Title 17, typically referred to as 17 CFR § 249.310](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/249.310) . That is where the name of the form is given -- "Form 10-K, for annual and transition reports ..."

I can't find any information as to why they chose "K" instead of some other letter.

Comment: I think [this](https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/files/docs/historical/congressional/securities-exchange-act.pdf) is the original.  There's only one _K)_ in the whole thing and it isn't about the periodic filings in Section 13.